Want to change animation speed of all child elements on hovering on the parent element


body {
  padding: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(15, 19, 24);
}

.m {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.m * {
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

.m *:hover {
  animation: /*animation of all children*/
  0.4s ease 1s infinite normal both;
}

.m1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: Pulses2 1.8s ease 1.2s infinite normal both;
}

.m2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: Pulses1 1.8s ease-out 1s infinite normal forwards;
}

.m4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: Pulses1 1.8s ease-out 1.4s infinite normal forwards;
}

.m3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 241, 227);
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: -2;
  animation: Pulses3 1.8s ease 1s infinite normal forwards;
  filter: blur(6px);
}

@keyframes Pulses1 {
  from {
    transform: scale(0%);
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(280%);
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes Pulses2 {
  0% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
    transform: scale(100%);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 243, 139);
    transform: scale(115%);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
    transform: scale(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes Pulses3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(990%);
    opacity: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 176, 97);
    ;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(400%);
    opacity: 2%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 176, 97);
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(700%);
    opacity: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 196, 57);
  }
}
<div class="m">
  <div class="m1"></div>
  <div class="m2"></div>
  <div class="m3"></div>
  <div class="m4"></div>
</div>



Here m is the parent and m1 to m4 all child have their own animation. Applying hover transition to increase animation speed to every element causes each element to respond individually. I wanted that if hovering on the parent element makes child elements faster.
I was going for calling all child element together but all elements have unique animations. How it can be done?

.m:hover * { animation: /animation of all children/ 0.4s ease 1s infinite normal both; }

If you want to trigger :hover
on parent element and affect children, apply it to parent element with appropriate children selector. As you want to alter only animation speed, use animation-duration:
.m:hover * {
    animation-duration: /*animation of all children*/ 0.4s;
}


To change the animation speed of all child elements when hovering over the parent element, you can use CSS custom properties (variables) to control the animation duration. This way, you can dynamically adjust the animation duration on hover.
Here's how you can modify your code:
Define a custom property for the animation duration.
Use this custom property in the animation definitions.
Change the custom property value on hover.
Here's the portion of the code you need to add/modify:
:root {
  --animation-duration: 1.8s;
  --animation-duration-hover: 0.9s;
}

.m {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}

/* Apply the custom property to child elements' animations */
.m1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: Pulses2 var(--animation-duration) ease 1.2s infinite normal both;
}

.m2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: Pulses1 var(--animation-duration) ease-out 1s infinite normal forwards;
}

.m4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: Pulses1 var(--animation-duration) ease-out 1.4s infinite normal forwards;
}

.m3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 241, 227);
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: -2;
  animation: Pulses3 var(--animation-duration) ease 1s infinite normal forwards;
  filter: blur(6px);
}

/* Change the animation duration on hover */
.m:hover .m1,
.m:hover .m2,
.m:hover .m3,
.m:hover .m4 {
  animation-duration: var(--animation-duration-hover);
}

/* Keyframes remain unchanged */
@keyframes Pulses1 {
  from {
    transform: scale(0%);
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(280%);
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes Pulses2 {
  0% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
    transform: scale(100%);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 243, 139);
    transform: scale(115%);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
    transform: scale(100%);
  }
}

@keyframes Pulses3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(990%);
    opacity: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 176, 97);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(400%);
    opacity: 2%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 176, 97);
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(700%);
    opacity: 0%;
    background-color: rgb(255, 196, 57);
  }
}


The animation-duration property is responsible for the animation speed. Other questions, how to compare frames of current and "accelerated" animation.


body {
  background-color: rgb(15, 19, 24);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100dvh;
}

.m {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  position:relative;
}

.m *{
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.m:hover * {
  animation-duration: .4s;
}

.m1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
  z-index: 2;
  animation: Pulses2 1.8s ease 1.2s infinite normal both;
}

.m2 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
  z-index: 1;
  animation: Pulses1 1.8s ease-out 1s infinite normal forwards;
}

.m4 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
  animation: Pulses1 1.8s ease-out 1.4s infinite normal forwards;
}

.m3 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 241, 227);
  z-index: -1;
  animation: Pulses3 1.8s ease 1s infinite normal forwards;
  filter: blur(6px);
}

@keyframes Pulses1 {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(2.8);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes Pulses2 {
  0% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 243, 139);
    transform: scale(1.15);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: rgb(255, 191, 29);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes Pulses3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(9.9);
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgb(255, 176, 97);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(4);
    opacity: .02;
    background-color: rgb(255, 176, 97);
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(7);
    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgb(255, 196, 57);
  }
}
<div class="m">
  <div class="m1"></div>
  <div class="m2"></div>
  <div class="m3"></div>
  <div class="m4"></div>
</div>



